# How to remove #anchor from a URL page?

Tags: java, html, anchor

First one, I`m sorry asking again this theme, i've tried lot of times and ways before ask here.

I've used a "template" to create a onepage website (my own business), so when I put it online  saw lot of anchors on URL, I really would like to remove the #anchor from URL but as I'm a dummie in that theme, I didin't find any way to do that works.

the web site is: www.continuumprivate.com.br , as you can see, if you click in the buttons apper in URL xxx.com/#slide01...  ...com/#slide02.

Some tries I did, I guess I don't know where out the codes (custom.js, index.html jquery.js) maybe this is the motive that i didint got it. So if you guys can help a newbie I'll be very grateful.

(sry for the bad English!) and thank you in advance.

Comment: If you built an SPA ([Single-Page Application](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application), aka "onepage website") using some kind of framework, then that is how those kinds of applications work, to keep track if which view is active on that single page. Live with it.

Comment: I can live with it, but it's not possible that i can`t hide from URL, i don't wanna remove from code.

Comment: If you remove it from the URL, it mean that users cannot bookmark the view they are on. The SPA frameworks jump through hoops to get that functionality working, so why wouldn't you want it? Anyway, it entirely depends on which SPA framework you're using, whether you can disable that feature. You should **read the documentation** of the framework to learn if you can.

Comment: Well, it's a short SPA website, but I understand that most programmers don't like remove anchors from the URL, it's a personal choice. I will look again the documentation if there is such a possibility, thank you for your help anyway!